# group dictionaries and get count

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
list1 = [{'name': 'maik','is_payed': 1, 'brand': 'HP', 'count': 1, 'items': [{'device': 'mouse', 'count': 110}]},{'name': 'milanie','is_payed': 0, 'brand': 'dell', 'count':10, 'items': [{'device': 'bales', 'count': 200}]}]

list2 = [{'name': 'maik','is_payed': 0, 'brand': 'HP', 'count': 20, 'items': [{'device': 'mouse', 'count': 1}]},{'name': 'nikola','is_payed': 1, 'brand': 'toshiba', 'count':10, 'items': [{'device': 'hard', 'count': 20}]}]
my_list= list1 + list2

count = pd.DataFrame(my_list).groupby(['name', 'is_payed'])
final_list_ = []
for commande, group in count:
    print(commande)
    records = group.to_dict("records")

    final_list_.append({"name": commande[0],
                    "payed": commande[1],
                    "occurrence": len(group),
                    "items": pd.DataFrame(records).groupby('device').agg(
        occurrence=('device', 'count')).reset_index().to_dict('records')})
```

I don't know how can I get it like this:
the `'payed'` field is like this **payed/total_commands**

for example lets take `maik` he has two commands one is payed and the other one is not, so the final result will be like this:

```
{'name': 'maik','payed': 1/2, 'brand': 'HP', 'count': 21, 'items': [{'device': 'mouse', 'count': 111}]}
```

Comment: Is this question strictly about how to maintain/calculate the "payed" datapoint? I ask because there are a bunch of things related to brand and counts that I think could be important but you do not appear to be grouping by enough information to summarize them.

Comment: can you give me more details

Comment: what happens if "Maik" has a brand of "toshiba"?  How are things summed up then?

Comment: i just want to group by "name" and get the "payed" point because I am just tracking the payed / not payed commands

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to group by "name" and are only interested in the "played" values, let's concentrate on that and ignore the other data.

So for our purposes, your starting data looks like:

```
my_list = [
    {'name': 'maik', 'is_payed': 1},
    {'name': 'milanie', 'is_payed': 0},
    {'name': 'maik', 'is_payed': 0},
    {'name': 'nikola', 'is_payed': 1}
]
```

Now let's take a first pass over this data and count up the number of times we see a name and the number of times that name corresponds to an "is_payed" flag

```
results = {}
for item in my_list:
    key = item["name"]
    results.setdefault(key, {"sum": 0, "count": 0})
    results[key]["count"] += 1
    results[key]["is_payed"] += item["is_payed"]
```

At this point we have a dictionary that will look like:

```
{
    'maik': {'is_payed': 1, 'count': 2},
    'milanie': {'is_payed': 0, 'count': 1},
    'nikola': {'is_payed': 1, 'count': 1}
}
```

Now we will take a pass over this dictionary and create our true final result:

```
results = [
    {"name": key, "payed": f"{value['is_payed']}/{value['count']}"}
    for key, value in results.items()
]
```

Giving us:

```
[
    {'name': 'maik', 'payed': '1/2'},
    {'name': 'milanie', 'payed': '0/1'},
    {'name': 'nikola', 'payed': '1/1'}
]
```